# How to escape quotes and special chars from string and pass it to JS onClick method?

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, dom-events

I have PHP Script / HTML

```
$string1 = 'Foo';
$string2 = 'Bar';
$string3 = 'This string contains some URL';
$string4 = 'This string contains multi-line short description which contains single quotes, double quotes and some comma characters as well.';
```

Here is my onClick

```
<a class="someClass" title="someTitle" href="#" onclick="someFunction('<?php echo $string1; ?>', '<?php echo $string2; ?>', '<?php echo $string3; ?>', '<?php echo $string4; ?>')">Click Here</a>
```

But while receiving, I am getting all sorts of string parsing errors on `someFunction()`

Comment: can you add code of someFunction. It's difficult to answer this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php side use:

```
<?php echo addslashes($string1); ?>
```

And inside someFunction( string1 ) use:

```
string1 = string1.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

To get the normal value of the string;